# One Conditional formating macro overwrite the other

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have two VBA macros that do some conditional formatting in an excel sheet, they work separately - but when I run both macros one overrides the other in the formatting rules and I simply can not see what to do

```
 Sub BetingetFormateringAktiviteter()
'
' Makro1 Makro
' Betinget formateringsregler alle Aktiviteter

    Dim rng As Range, offrng As Range
    Dim arrAkt() As Variant
    Dim arrCol() As Variant
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Set rng = Range("J10:J40,Q10:Q39,X10:X40,AE10:AE39,AL10:AL40,AS10:AS40,AZ10:AZ39,BG10:BG40,BN10:BN39,BU10:BU40,CB10:CB40,CI10:CI38,CP10:CP40")
    Set offrng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
    arrAkt = Array("""S""", """A""", """FE""", """SF""", """T""", """TK""", """TH""", """SY""", """V""", """VA""", """L1""", """L2""")

    arrCol = Array(RGB(255, 255, 0), RGB(0, 255, 255), RGB(255, 192, 0), RGB(255, 192, 0), RGB(49, 255, 33), RGB(0, 176, 240), RGB(255, 204, 255), RGB(255, 0, 0), RGB(184, 204, 228), RGB(230, 184, 183), RGB(226, 107, 10), RGB(196, 189, 151))
    iCount = 0
    'Debug.Print offrng.Address: Stop
    
    
    Dim s As Variant
    For Each s In arrAkt
        With rng
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="= " & s
            .FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
            With .FormatConditions(iCount + 1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = arrCol(iCount)
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        With offrng
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "= " & s
            .FormatConditions(iCount + 1).Interior.Color = rng.FormatConditions(iCount + 1).Interior.Color
            .FormatConditions(iCount + 1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        iCount = iCount + 1
    Next
End Sub

Sub BetingetFormateringLøSøHelligdage()
'
' Makro1 Makro
' Betinget formateringsregler alle Aktiviteter

    Dim rng As Range, offrng As Range
    Set rng = Range("G10:G40,N10:N39,U10:U40,AB10:AB39,AI10:AI40,AP10:AP40,AW10:AW39,BD10:BD40,BK10:BK39,BR10:BR40,BY10:BY40,CF10:CF38,CM10:CM40")
    Set offrngR3 = rng.Offset(0, 3)
    Set offrngR4 = rng.Offset(0, 4)
    Set offrngL1 = rng.Offset(0, -1)
    Set offrngL2 = rng.Offset(0, -2)

    'Debug.Print offrng.Address: Stop
    
    Dim s As Variant

    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=" SAND"
        .FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 12632256
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    With offrngL1
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "= SAND"
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With offrngL2
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "= SAND"
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    
    With offrngR3
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "= SAND"
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    
    With offrngR4
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.Cells(1).Address(0, 0) & "= SAND"
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting is based on a set of rules, which are applied one after the other. So, if you don't want rule two to overwrite rule one, you might just reverse their order.

In order to verify if this might be working, you can check the rules of the conditional formatting, and try to alter the sequence of the followed rules, as indicated by the blue rectangle in this screenshot (pardon the Dutch, I don't have an English Excel), you might find this using "Condtional Formatting", "Manage rules":

[image: Condtional formatting, manage rules]

For your information, the sentence "Regel (toegepast in aangegeven volgorde)" means "Rule (applied in the indicated sequence)".

Another option is the checkbox "Stoppen indien Waar", which means "Stop in case of True". When this is checked, conditional formatting is stopped once a "TRUE" value is found, which is another way to prevent one rule overwriting the other.